# Angular JS Send Element in Event

Tags: html, angularjs

Hopefully this is as easy as I think it is and my brain is just dead, but I can't find anyone doing this online.

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      <ion-item class="item-stable"
                ng-click="toggleGroup(group)"
                ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(group)}">
          <i class="icon" ng-class="isGroupShown(group) ? 'ion-minus' : 'ion-plus'"></i>
        &nbsp;
        Group {{group.name}}
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item-accordion"
                ng-repeat="item in group.items"
                ng-show="isGroupShown(group)">
        {{item}}
      </ion-item>
    </div>
```

example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORXWkp

Except I don't want to have the "group". There will only be one div at the top, so I need a way to send the div through the isGroupShown() methods.

I want to reuse these methods elsewhere, so I am not wanting to get the element and change it that way. ie:

```
var multibutton = angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName("multi-files"));
```

and then use multibutton in the isGroupShown() methods.

EDIT: Basically, I want to know the parent div of when these functions are run.

Comment: You can use the `$event` object in to get the target element for clicks, but that's about it. What is your use case for getting the parent div? You should rarely/never actually need something like that in angular (explaining why it's not easy to do it).

Answer (score 0):

1) maybe you'd use

```
var multibutton = angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName("multi-files")[0]);
```

instead of:

```
var multibutton = angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName("multi-files"));
```

because getElement**s**ByClassName returns array, compared to `getElementById`

2) maybe the problem is with local variable declaration. just remove `var` :
`var multibutton = ...` to 
 `multibutton =.....` 
and then you can reuse that outside of that function.

Comment: Well, no, I just added that last part to prevent an answer of someone telling me to do  the multibutton and then reference multibutton in my isGroupShown method. That works, but doesn't allow me to reuse the function.

Comment: @user1427105 i have updated answer, and added second solution. see,that may work.